# How do I change the color of a var in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```js
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Mar 5, 2021  00:00:00").getTime();
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " ngày " + hours + " giờ " +
        minutes + " phút " + seconds + " giây";
      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I need to change the color of var days, hours, minutes, seconds...

Comment: Put styled `<span>` HTML tags around them.

Comment: It seems you need to show the `HTML` where this var is displayed

Answer (score 2):

Although @lax48's answer would work fine, it'd be better to use css classes in you want multiple preset colors for easier code maintenance later. 
**Example CSS**

```
.red { color: red }
.blue { color: navy }
.green { color: green }
```

**Example Javascript**

```
let elem = document.getElementById("demo")    
elem.innerHTML += "<span class='red'>" + days + "</span> days"
               + "<span  class='blue'>" + hours + " hours</span>"
               + "<span class='green'>" + minutes + " minutes</span>"
               + "<span class='red'>" + seconds+ " seconds</span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to style your HTML. In order to style portion of text you usually use a `span` tag with a `style="color: YOUR_COLOR;"` attribute.

So your HTML should be:

```html
<span style="color: YOUR_COLOR;">4</span> ngày <span style="color: YOUR_COLOR;">5</span> giờ
```

So in JavaScript you will need to write:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color: YOUR_COLOR;\">" + days + "</span> ngày <span style=\"color: YOUR_COLOR;\">" + hours + "ecc";
```

See this to understand how to write color codes and to see the full list of the color names: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp .

See this jsfiddle as a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1b5ed8cw/ .